# how to get telegram CHANNEL member list?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How can I get telegram CHANNEL member list? (not GROUP)
I am not an admin or owner of the channel but can I get the member list? I am just a vistor of that CHANNEL

Anybody know the answer please let me know
I have searched for this already but there is no one who has same question

Sorry for bad English, I don't use English

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for that being ordinary subscriber. Member list can be accessed by channel admins only.

Comment: isn't there any way if I use telethon or API? or telegram bot..?

Comment: No. This is native Telegram limitation.

Comment: by the way, i am curious about whether i can get member list of GROUP. not channel. do you know about it?